# Not getting form.controls of formArray from @Input() form in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a form which has multiple types of controls in a `FormArray` in `Angular7`.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(); form.reset()">
  <app-list-fields [form]="form"></app-list-fields>
</form>
```

Receiving that form in a component like.

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
```

But when calling to the controls of this form array, I am getting nothing.

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="main" >
  <div *ngFor="let list of form.get('main').controls; let i = index"  [formGroupName]="i">
<div class="campform" *ngIf="list.type==1">
      <div class="clr-row">
        <div class="clr-col-12" style="text-align:right">
          <a class='btn' (click)="removeListField(i)">X</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-row">
        <div class="clr-col-12">
          <h5>{{ list.name | titlecase }}</h5>
          <input type="hidden" formControlName="name" value="{{list.value}}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" formControlName="type" value="1">
      <div class="clr-col-4 gutterpadl gutterpadr">
        <clr-select-container>
          <select clrSelect formControlName="operator">
            <option ngValue="">Select List</option>
            <option ngValue="=">Equals</option>
            <option ngValue="!=">Not Equal</option>
            <option ngValue="LIKE">Contains</option>
            <option ngValue="NOT LIKE">Does Not Contain</option>
            <option ngValue="LIKE_">Begins With</option>
            <option ngValue="_LIKE">Ends With</option>
            <option ngValue="empty">Is Empty</option>
            <option ngValue="notempty">Is Not Empty</option>
          </select>
        </clr-select-container>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col-4 gutterpadl gutterpadr">
        <input type="text" formControlName="operand" class="borderfield" required placeholder="Enter List Name">
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col-12">
        <span *ngIf="form.get('main').length > 1 && i+1 != form.get('main').length">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="condition" value="or">Or
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" formControlName="condition" value="and">And
          </label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I use `value` instead of `controls` is working fine, but I then I can add an only single character to any input control.

NOTE: The same thing I am using in another control which has FormGroup and FormArray in the same component, it is working fine.

Comment: remove the "value={{list.value}}", use `<div *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">` -the *ngIf- to avoid initial errors and check for another errors.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
<div class="campform" *ngIf="list.type==1">
```

to

```
<div class="campform" *ngIf="list.controls.type.value==1">
```

And at all other places where the value was required, it is working fine now.